# Odd changes to command-prompt title-line under Windows 10

Tags: batch-file, windows-10, titlebar

When you run a program from the command-line, the title of the command-prompt window temporarily changes to include the command being executed. Once the command has finished, the title returns to its original value. For instance:

[image] ==> [image] ==> [image]

Over the years, I've accumulated many short, "utility" batch-files: most were written on, and mostly used on, a Windows 7 machine, where they all work "as expected". However, I recently noticed that *some* batch files behave oddly when run under Windows 10: the title-bar is **not** reset after the command has finished. For example, after repeatedly running a batch-file I have called `nd` (that moves to the "next directory"), the title-bar looks like this:

[image]

After doing some digging, a minimal example is:

**aa.bat**:

```
(bb)
```

**bb.bat** (which is on the `PATH`):

```
dir
```

The key seems to be a combination of the first batch-file *transferring* control to the second, instead of calling it (things work as expected if `aa.bat` contains `(call bb)`) **and** being inside a `(...)` construct (simply having `bb` on its own also works as expected)<sup>**1**</sup>.

Under Windows 7, all variants work "as expected" and return the title-bar to its original value after the command completes. In my case, Windows 10 is version **10.0.17763.615** and Windows 7 is **6.1.7601**.

*Does anyone know **(a)** why Windows 10 behaves this way, or – more importantly – **(b)** is there a simpler way of stopping it without having to replace all such "chain" invocations with, say `(call bb && goto :eof)`<sup>**1**</sup>?*

---

<sup>**1**</sup> A more realistic situation, and the reason for the enclosing `(...)`, is that the invocation of the second batch-file is from within an `IF condition ( ... ) ELSE ( ... )` type of statement, and I *don't* want control to return to the original batch file. Using `call` and then `goto :eof` after control *has* returned will work, but feels a little awkward.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard Re. your second comment, the thing is I _am_ calling another batch file, not a standalone executable. Re. your first comment, there _is_ a difference... `call bb` or `(call bb)` will pause execution of the calling batch-file, run `bb.bat` and then _resume_ execution of the original batch-file when it (bb) exits. However, `bb` or `(bb)` will _transfer_ execution to the other batch file: when it exits, control will _not_ return to the original batch file. In the cases where I saw this problem, I _wanted_ this behaviour, so turning `(bb)` into `(call bb)` _would_ need `goto :eof`.

Comment: The contents of `bb` does not seem to make a difference (simply containing `dir` exhibits the behaviour)... it seems to be only the way it is called from `aa` (_not_ using `call`; and enclosed in `(...)`). Most of the time the change to the title isn't _crucial_ (as you say, I can always reset it), but it's somewhat annoying that after a while the title of my command-prompt window is littered with previously executed command-lines.

Comment: The problem with explicitly setting the title in my scripts is that it will overwrite whatever the current title is (I often have two or more command-prompt windows open, each for different purposes, and set the title to reflect each purpose – those distinctions would be lost if [some of] my scripts reset the title). Appreciate the ideas though!

Comment: ok, the only other way then would be to move `bb` to a label and `call` the label, anyway I am commenting your post to pieces :) will cleanup.